# List of plans or strategic themes

Tags: strategy

I know of lists that cover tactical themes and endgame themes. I can't find a list of plans or strategic themes in the middlegame.

Could someone help me out with this list? A link would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the *table of contents* from classical works such as

[Modern Chess Strategy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486202909), by Pachman, and

[The Middlegame](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1880673959), by Euwe and Kramer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge question.

I can't help you with a list of themes, but look up the games of GM Tigran Petrosian (world champion from 1963-69.)  You'll see how a master chooses moves based upon positional considerations.  [Here's a list of some of his games](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1014968).  The general consensus is that he plays to remove good moves from his opponents, leaving them only bad moves.  But making a bad move against a GM leads to a loss.  [My System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1880673851) is a classic that describes this style of play.